# How to get index of clicked link in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my markup:

```
<div>
<h2><a href="link-here">Link Text</a></h2>
<p>Description</p>
<h2><a href="link-here">Link Text</a></h2>
<p>Description</p>
<h2><a href="link-here">Link Text</a></h2>
<p>Description</p>
.. Unknown number of such elements...
</div>
```

When a user clicks a link I wanted to get its index. I tried to use `$(this).index();` but it returns zero. How can I get the link?

Comment: Get the index of the parent element instead. The anchor elements don't have siblings (which is why their index is `0`).

Comment: @JoshCrozier So I should use `$(this).closest('h2').index();` ?

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').on('click',function(){
        alert($('a').index($(this)));
    });
});
```

in jQuery documentation (https://api.jquery.com/index/) we read:

> If .index() is called on a collection of elements and a DOM element or
>   jQuery object is passed in, .index() returns an integer indicating the
>   position of the passed element relative to the original collection.

Comment: This will work only if there are no other links on the page before these.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your issue is that `index()` will return a result relative to the parent of `this`, which is always the h2 element.
In other words, `index()` will always be zero for your case.

However, if you [read the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/index/), you'll find that `index()` also has some variants, such as the 2nd option where you can specify how to retrieve the index from a list of items via a selector.

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/d7rpuv6d/ (please open the console to see the result)